# Combining RDFa Lite author schema and rel="author" HTML markup

Tags: html, schema.org, rel, rdfa, rel-author

Is there any way to retain the HTML `rel` part of the below snippet:

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="AboutPage">
   <address property="author" typeof="person">Contact <a rel="author" href="mailto:your-email@example.com" property="name">My Name</a></address>
</body>
```

without getting this warning:

```
AboutPage                0 ERRORS  1 WARNINGS
@type           AboutPage
author  
    @type       Person
    name        My Name
!   author      The property author is not recognized by Google for an object of type Person.
        @type   Unspecified Type
```

Just a `rel`:

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="AboutPage">
   <address>Contact <a rel="author" href="mailto:your-email@example.com" >My Name</a></address>
</body>
```

gives

```
AboutPage                0 ERRORS  0 WARNINGS
@type           AboutPage
author  
    @type       Unspecified Type
```

I cannot seem to give the `rel` a `type` without `property="author"` which then causes weird `author` duplicates of various types.

I'm aware that I could just remove the `rel` entirely or move it to `meta` data, but if the Structured Data Testing Tool insists on recognizing the `rel="author"` then there must be a way to give it a `type`, no?

Comment: Google doesn't give any special treatment for author schema anymore.  You should just remove it.

Comment: And yet it is still required for each BlogPosting.  Since I am building a single author blog, my plan was to have the Author marked up and visible on the WebPage but hidden in the individual posts since "written by me" and "also written by me" would get repetitive.

Comment: I don't think there is a rich snippet for BlogPosting either.

Comment: It is not all about what currently generates a rich snippet...

Comment: I don't know of any other benefit.  It doesn't help rankings.  Browsers and users ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rel` attribute has two different purposes, which might conflict:

- **Plain HTML:** providing a link type
- **RDFa:** providing a property (just like the `property` attribute, but with some technical differences)

In both of your snippets, it’s interpreted¹ to be the [Schema.org property `author`](https://schema.org/author), not the [link type `author`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/links.html#link-type-author).

The best general way to prevent such mix-ups is not to use `vocab`. Use `prefix` instead (or rely on the [RDFa Core Initial Context](https://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1)):

```html
<!-- using 'prefix' -->

<body prefix="s: http://schema.org/" typeof="s:AboutPage">
  <address property="s:author" typeof="s:Person">
    Contact <a rel="author" href="mailto:your-email@example.com" property="s:name">My Name</a>
  </address>
</body>
```

```html
<!-- rely on the RDFa Core Initial Context, which defines 'schema' -->

<body typeof="schema:AboutPage">
  <address property="schema:author" typeof="schema:Person">
    Contact <a rel="author" href="mailto:your-email@example.com" property="schema:name">My Name</a>
  </address>
</body>
```

Note that Google will now report an error:

> The property `http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-author` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `Person`.

This is no problem, you can ignore it, as the generated URI shows that Google’s SDTT correctly understands that the `rel` value is a link type (which might also be used as RDF property), and it’s no longer interpreting it to be a Schema.org property. It also gives this error when using properties from other vocabularies than Schema.org, which is a perfectly fine and useful thing to do.

---

¹ Side note: If I understand [list item 7](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/#additional-rules) correctly, an RDFa parser should ignore the `rel` attribute in your specific case, because you have the `property` attribute on the same element, and your `rel` doesn’t contain a CURIE/URI value.